# dynamic mySQL query with increment operator

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to create an online quiz application. I have a question table with question#, question and options. The requirement is to display one question and ans in the UI at a time and when user clicks on next proceed to another. I have the below code but the select query is not working when I put 'i'. I tried to put 1 just for debugging and its working.

```
  <form  name="myform">  

    <table>
<%
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String localhost="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pr1";
Connection  connection=DriverManager.getConnection(localhost, "root", "root"); 
Statement st=connection.createStatement();

int i= 1;

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from question where Qno=i");    
while(rs.next())
{
%>
            <tr><td> <%=rs.getString("question")%></td></tr>
            <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="padding: 10px;">A .&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="option" value="optionA"/><%=rs.getString("optionA")%></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="padding: 10px;">B .&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="option" value="optionB"/><%=rs.getString("optionB")%></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="padding: 10px;">C .&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="option" value="optionC"/><%=rs.getString("optionC")%></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="padding: 10px;">D .&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="option" value="optionD"/><%=rs.getString("optionD")%></td></tr>
            <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="next" value="Next"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" value="Previous"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" value="Test Summary"/></td></tr>
<%
}
%>
  </table>
<%
   if(request.getParameter("next")!=null)
  {i++;
  System.out.print(i);
  }
     rs.close();



    st.close();
    connection.close();
    }
catch(Exception e)
{

    e.printStackTrace();
    }

%>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is not php, it is not going to expand the variable `i` within the string containing the sql command.

At its simplest form, use string concatenation:

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from question where Qno=" + i);
```

If you get any parameter from the users, then use prepared statements with parameters to avoid sql injection.